# What version of Flash Player is suitable for Win 10 and where to get it?

Tags: flash, flash-player, windows-10-preview

I'm on Win 10 and every time a page wants to use the Flash Player, it asks me to follow a link to install it. When I try to follow the link, I get to an almost empty page without anything clickable nor downloadable.

I figure it's because Win 10 is so new so they haven't made an official release for that version yet. However, I'm hoping that I can use a version developed for another platform.

1. Can I do that?
2. Which version should I target?
3. Where do I obtain the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash for Internet Explorer is part of Windows 10 like in Windows 8.x. For other browser like Chrome or Firefox you have to download a plugin ("Plugin-based browsers") from here:

https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html

Comment: The one that's built in the IE works improperly. I get something on the screen but it's incorrectly sized. Not sure if it's because the Flash built into IE sucks or the design of the page I'm accessing that sucks. But something sucks. Statistically speaking, I'd blame IE but things change and it might be something else.